# Solve an equation for a product

Tags: equation-solving

I have an equation `a = bcd/fg` and I have another one that I can take `bcd` out of. Easy enough to do by hand, but *Mathematica* won't let me solve for `bcd` (need to for completeness).

```
Solve[h + j + k - (l + m*n + b*c)*d == 0, bcd]
```

> Solve::ivar: b c d is not a valid variable. >>

Comment: You can expand this, substitute b*c*d as bcd, so that it is a variable. Then you can solve.

Comment: Actually kind of tricky. One way is to add an equation `b*c*d==bcd`, the solve for `{bcd,b}` for example. If you solve for only `bcd` you get an empty solution set because a condition is imposed that makes the solution set nongeneric.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to attack this is to force the substitution. Observe that

```
Expand[a1 + b*a2 + c1*b + d*c2 - (e + a1*x + g*e)*y]

a1 + a2 b + b c1 + c2 d - e y - e g y - a1 x y
```

has the term you want. So make the substitution

```
eqn=Expand[a1 + b*a2 + c1*b + d*c2 - (e + a1*x + g*e)*y] //. a1 x y -> z
```

Then you can

```
Solve[eqn == 0, z]
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
Eliminate[{h + j + k - (l + m*n + b*c)*d == 0, 
  bcd == b c d}, c]

(* ==> h + j + k - d l - d m n == bcd *)
```

I see that Bill's answer was just accepted while I typed, but it's worth pointing out (as Daniel did) that in order to solve for `bcd`, you have to add a definition for it to the set of equations. And in that case, `Eliminate` is easier than `Solve` because you just have to pick one of the variables `bcd` depends on as the one to be eliminated (in general, one variable can be eliminated for every additional equation you impose).

Answer (score 0):

```
    Solve[h + j + k - (l + m*n + b*c)*d == 0, b][[1, 1, 2]]*c*d

   (*   h + j + k - d l - d m n   *)
```

?